# Converting Fiqured in Words with Processmaker

Tags: processmaker

i create two input in the dynafom and assign the following variable
@totalPlace_amount --- this variable represent the amount in fiqured .
@amount_in_words------this variable represent the fiqure in words .
i want if someone enter the amount in the figured input , should automatically get the values in words.

Comment: Please see [Ask] to learn how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

What version of ProcessMaker are you using?  We recommend that you upgrade first to the latest version - 4.0.13